# How to link css in html

Tags: html, css

This is my web link https://dcnetwork.xyz. Here my CSS is not working i dont know the reason these are my files index.html and style.css

[image]
[image]

[Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmEeG.jpg)
[Css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLjgd.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take some time to read the link on how to ask a question. This will help avoid your question being downvoted na dhelp others to reproduce the problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

the only error I can see is that you didn't close  tag (end of the line 4)
Just add '>' at the end of the line.

CSS file loads and works correctly for me.

If you cannot see the CSS changes - sometimes it helps to do hard refresh/reload:

- Chrome, Firefox, or Edge for Windows: Press Ctrl+F5 (If that doesn't
  work, try Shift+F5 or Ctrl+Shift+R).
- Chrome or Firefox for Mac: Press Shift+Command+R.

Answer (score -2):

we have to simply write <link r el="stylesheet" h r e f=""
in head section only showing in below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link r e l=" s t l y e sheet" h r e f="styles.css">
  <title>Movie Booking</title>
  </head>
</html>
```

here "styles.css" is file of c s s containing c s s properties